# Recommendation on economics books for a statistician

Tags: self-study, books

I have mainly an statistics/informatics background and i have basically not knowledge in economics.

What some good books to star given my background?

Edit:

My principal interest is stock market analysis, investing and risk modeling.

I have a degree in statistics and other informatic engineering(something like CS), i don't have problems with math-heavy books if it helps me to build a solid understanding.

Comment: Some additional details may be helpful: what do you want to get from reading economics books? Are you studying for a degree, or do you want to understand a specific subfield? Also, what kind of statistics/informatics background do you have? Did you study a lot of math (what kind)?

Comment: @Giskard, edited.

Comment: Perhaps [Quant.SE] may be a better fit for this question. (Not sure.)